# Spark unfinished stages. Spark app is idle

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I've faced with situation when running cluster on AWS EMR, that one stage remained 'running' when execution plan continue to progress. Look at screen from Spark UI (job 4 has running tasks, however job 7 in progress). My question is how to debug such situation, if there are any tips that I can find at DAG? 
My thought that it could be some memory issue because data is tough, and there are a lot of spills to disk. However I am wondering why spark stays idle for hour. Is it related to driver memory issues?

[image]

UPD1:

Based on Ravi requests:

> (1) check the time since they are running and the GC time also. If GC
>   time is >20% of the execution time it means that u r throttled by the
>   memory.

No, it is not an issue. 
[image: Executors tab]

> (2) check number of active tasks in the same page.
>   That's really weird, there are executors with more active tasks than cores capacity (3x time more for some of executors), however I do not see any executors failures.
>   [image: active tasks]
>   (3) see if all executors are equally spending time in running the job
>   Not an issue
>   (4) what u showed above is the job what abt stages etc? are they also
>   paused for ever?

[image: stages]

Comment: Though job 4 shows running, it is under list of `completed jobs`. I gues some events were dropped by Spak event listener and hence the UI is showing so. When events are dropped, it is logged in driver logs.

Comment: Reg driver being idle for more than an hour, do you see nay jobs running on Spark UI. If yes, then there are running jobs. If no, use `jstack <pid>` to check what is running on the driver.

Comment: my 2 cents. Did u go to `Executor` tab? and see how many executors are running? (1) check the time since they are running and the GC time also. If GC time is >20% of the execution time it means that u r throttled by the memory. (2) check number of active tasks in the same page. (3) see if all executors are equally spending time in running the job --if timings are skewed then ur data is skewed; in which case try to do `dataframe.repartition(100)` and try again with increased executors. (4) what u showed above is the job what abt stages etc? are they also paused for ever?

Comment: @ravi I've updated the post with info 1,2,3,4

Comment: Things look good. To be double sure enable Ganglia in EMR and check free-mem; load-avg-1min across all nodes. can u disable 'consistant view' in EMR, if enabled? u read and write to s3? can u switch to hdfs (enable HDFS inthe EMR)? Just to rule out resource issues can u add more task nodes (some 50+; better go with spot instances as they are 10-30% cost of on-demand). Also i prefer 1 core per executor. looks like u gave 16GB/executor but only 3 gb is used --so refine ur spark submit command.